# Creating a trigger that sets a timestamp on UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table that has 3 columns. One is a record, one is created_time, and the last one is updated_at. I want to create a stored procedure that changes updated_at to NOW() when a record is UPDATED. Each row also has an id called id. I don't have any initial code to show as I am slightly confused on how triggers work. I understand that my trigger would be an update or record, but how do I tell the table to update its corresponding updated_at value to NOW().

I created my table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE keyvalue ( 
  id id,
  record VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You don't update the table. Rather, you write a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies the row that is about to be inserted by changing and returning the `NEW` variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION upd_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.updated_at := current_timestamp;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_trig BEFORE UPDATE ON keyvalue
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_trig();
```

Comment: Would the ```NEW.updated_at := current_timestamp;``` be ```NEW.updated_at := NOW()``` ? I need it to equal the current time.

Comment: They are identical.

Comment: if the application is changing, then this update is not necessary. how could it check that the field updated_at isn't already being updated?